# Magento2 Not able to update Address via GraphQl

Tags: magento2, graphql

I have try to update the address via GraphQl but somehow not working

[image]

Please guide me how can I solve this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **We Need existing Customer Address Id to update address.**

**Syntax**

```
mutation: {updateCustomerAddress(id: Int!, input: CustomerAddressInput) {CustomerAddress}}
```

**Example:**

```
mutation {
  updateCustomerAddress(id:5, input: {
    region: {
      region_id: 12,
      region: "California"
      region_code: "CA"
    }
    country_code: US
    street: ["123 Main Street"]
    telephone: "7777777777"
    postcode: "77777"
    city: "Phoenix"
    firstname: "Bob"
    lastname: "Loblaw"
    default_shipping: true
    default_billing: false
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

**Update**
Reference Link -> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/update-customer-address.html#customerAddressRegionInput

```
region -> DATA TYPE -> String -> The state or province name

region_code -> DATA TYPE -> String -> The address region code 

region_id -> DATA TYPE -> Int -> The unique ID for a pre-defined region
```

Comment: "message": "A region_id is required for the specified country code",

Comment: This is the error I am getting

Comment: I added the SS in my Ques

Comment: Please check my query region: {
      region_id: 12,
      region: "California"
      region_code: "CA"
    }  region_id inside into region:{} data. region_id must be valid value.

Comment: Yes i know that but I need to update address for QATAR & I don't think we have region for that. In that case what to do?

Comment: Please remove region_id after firstname, There is syntax error. region_id only used into region{} section only.

Comment: i removed still getting same error

Comment: You must be added valid data. And follow my query to replace your data. It's working. Please read Magento doc https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/update-customer-address.html

Comment: For countries like QATAR with country code QR, what needs to be passed in  region: {
      region: null
      region_code: null
      region_id: 0
    } ?

Comment: Please read doc with formate and its data type https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/update-customer-address.html#customerAddressRegionInput